# Forcing a formula's cell reference

Tags: excel-formula

Is it possible to force a formula's cell reference to not change?

For example if I had

```
=B1
```

in cell G1, and then inserted a column at column A.

I thought

```
=$B$1
```

may do it, but sadly not.

Comment: Not very clear for me what you mean.

Comment: If I add a column at A. I want the formula in cell G1 to remain as =B1

Comment: What does it become when you add a column at A?

Comment: @SardarUsama it will become `=C1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX:

```
=INDEX($1:$1048576,1,2)
```

The `1` is the row and the `2` is the column.  The `$1:$1048576` includes the whole sheet.

If you want to lock a range, like `Sum(B1:B4)` you can use this:

```
=SUM(INDEX($1:$1048576,1,2):INDEX($1:$1048576,4,2))
```

This will now always return the Sum of the range in `B1:B4` and not move off that range no matter how many columns are added or removed.

Comment: If B1:B4 were a named range, would the range hold with inserted columns, or would this same technique be required in the named range?

Comment: Only if the range is set with a formula like above.  Excel is very intelligent, it will change the reference in the named range also.  So it your named range was `=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$5` and you add a column in Sheet1 at Column A, Excel will automatically change it to `=Sheet1!$C$2:$C$5` and if that column were deleted you would get `#Ref` error.  So the formula would need to be: `=INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$1048576,2,2):INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$1048576,5,2)` @JacobEdmond